# Flutter: When using the camera package it shows E/BufferQueueProducer ... dequeueBuffer: attempting to exceed the max dequeued buffer count

Tags: android, flutter, dart, camera, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to build a camera app using Flutter using the [camera package](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera)

But every time I try to initialize the camera it shows me this error continuously filling up my debug console:

E/BufferQueueProducer(17882): [SurfaceTexture-0-17882-0](id:45da00000002,api:4,p:11024,c:17882) dequeueBuffer: attempting to exceed the max dequeued buffer count (4) [Screenshot of my debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBPTY.jpg)

I have tried following the official documentation from [Flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera) and [Pug.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/camera#handling-camera-access-permissions) websites but nothing seems to work.

I also tried following some blog posts by copy-pasting them to see if they worked but all of them gave me the same result. Some of the blogs I followed were

- [medium.com](https://medium.com/geekculture/build-a-camera-app-flutter-in-app-camera-825b829fe138)
- [blog.logrocket.com](https://blog.logrocket.com/photo-gallery-app-flutter/)
- [medium.com](https://medium.com/@fernnandoptr/how-to-use-camera-in-flutter-flutter-camera-package-44defe81d2da)

Here is my code

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../main.dart';

class CameraScreenTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraScreenTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<CameraScreenTest> createState() => _CameraScreenTestState();
}

class _CameraScreenTestState extends State<CameraScreenTest> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  CameraController? controller;
  bool _isCameraInitialized = false;

  void onNewCameraSelected(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    final previousCameraController = controller;
    // Instantiating the camera controller
    final CameraController cameraController = CameraController(
      cameraDescription,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
    );

    // Dispose the previous controller
    await previousCameraController?.dispose();

    // Replace with the new controller
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        controller = cameraController;
      });
    }

    // Update UI if controller updated
    cameraController.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
    });

    // Initialize controller
    try {
      await cameraController.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      print('Error initializing camera: $e');
    }

    // Update the Boolean
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _isCameraInitialized = controller!.value.isInitialized;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    onNewCameraSelected(cameras[0]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    final CameraController? cameraController = controller;

    // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
    if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      // Free up memory when camera not active
      cameraController.dispose();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // Reinitialize the camera with same properties
      onNewCameraSelected(cameraController.description);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _isCameraInitialized
          ? AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1 / controller!.value.aspectRatio,
              child: controller!.buildPreview(),
            )
          : Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Hoping to find a solution to the said problem

Comment: @finisinfinitatis I never found a solution.  As it was an annoyance but not a blocker, I just moved on and dealt with it.  My IDE was able to collapse / filter the logs, which made it more tolerable